# Почему не подключается xdebug.remote_enable?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, xdebug

подключаю `xdebug` в использую `php 7.2. fpm` вот таким образом указал в `php.ini`

```
xdebug.default_enable = On
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.idekey=PHP_IDE_CONFIG
```

но `phpinfo` выводит. Других файлов `php.ini` где это перебивалось нет.

```
xdebug.remote_enable    Off Off
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
```

объясните прочему

Comment: `Loaded Configuration Path` из `php_info` совпадает с тем файлом, что вы изменили?

Comment: А что в файле `/etc/php.d/xdebug.ini`?

Comment: проблема оказалось xdebug.so